# Conjugate closure and factor group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $N\unlhd K$ be a normal subgroup of a given group $K$ and let $$q:K\to K/N$$ be the natural quotient map. Let $A\subseteq K$ be a subset of $K$ and let the [conjugate closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_closure) of $A$ in $K$ be denoted by $\langle A^K\rangle$.

**Question**

Is it true that if $\langle A^K\rangle$ is Abelian, then $\langle(q(A))^{K/N}\rangle$ is also Abelian?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This follows because the image of $\langle A^K\rangle$ is a normal abelian subgroup of $K/N$ which contains the image of $A$, and hence also contains the conjugate closure of the image of $A$ (recall that the conjugate closure of a subset is the smallest normal subgroup containing that subset).

Answer (score 1):

Set $H:=\langle (q(A))^{K/N}\rangle $ and take $q(k)q(a)q(k)^{-1}$ be any element of $ (q(A))^{K/N}$ then clearly we have that $q(k)q(a)q(k)^{-1}=q(kak^{-1})\in q(\langle A^K\rangle)$. Hence a generating set of $H$ is in $q(\langle A^K\rangle)$, from this it follows that $H\subseteq q(\langle A^K\rangle)$.

If $\langle A^K\rangle$ is abelian, so is $q(\langle A^K\rangle)$ and any subgroup of it, in particular $H$ is abelian.